# Print a div with CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been searching alot for print a div with the CSS, but i didn't get the output that i want, i don't know why.

Here's the trigget to show the print popup:

```
    <button id="print" onclick="Popup('front')">HERE</button>
```

Here's my script:

```
    function Popup(data) {

    var div = document.getElementById(data).innerHTML;

    var mywindow = window.open('', 'new div', 'height=400,width=600');
    mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title></title>');
    mywindow.document.write( "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"ficha-tecnica-media.css\" type=\"text/css\" media=\"print\"/>" );
    mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
    mywindow.document.write(div);
    mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

    mywindow.print();
    mywindow.close();

    return true;
}
</script>
```

And in my `ficha-tecnica-media.css`:

```
@media print {
    body{
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
    table{
                font-size: 10px;
    }

    article{
                font-size: 10px;
    }
    img{
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
    }
}
```

If i put a `display:none` on `img` it works, but im trying to resize it, but it doesn't work. The `font-family` in body or `font-size` also don't work.. why?

Comment: So, to sum up, non of the `@media print` styles work, did I understand you correctly?

Comment: yes, @C14L . I guess the problem is the way i call the css directory